# Make Windows 7 style toolbar [outdated and unanswered]

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, toolbar

Windows 7 has a new appearance for `ToolBar` control:

[image: Windows 7 style ToolBar]

But my WinForms toolbar has the ugly classic gray

[image: Ugly Windows classic]

What do I have to do to make my `ToolBar` look like the first image

**EDIT**: I don't want to use gradients, I want to know if there's some P/Invoke (I use `ToolBar` instead of `ToolStrip`, 'cause `ToolBar` is nearer to native style controls than `ToolStrip`).

> Disclaimer
>   **THIS QUESTION HAD NO ANSWERS AND, NOW I USE C# INSTEAD OF VB.NET** (My question about vb.net are outdated for me, because I use c# instead.

Answer (score 2):

`Toolbar` control was replaced by `ToolStrip` control in Visual Studio 2010

You can follow [**this tutorial**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms233664(v=vs.100).aspx) for creating a professionally styled ToolStrip Control

Comment: It's difficult to understand 'cause there's not a understandable way to know where do I have to place every piece of code.    -    
 Is there some DLLImport function or a understandable tutorial (non MSDN)?

Comment: Why isn't understandable? Just above each snippet is well defined where should be inserted.

Comment: MSDN custom control tutorials does not says where do I have to place every snippet

Comment: *`In the StackView_Load event handler, copy and paste the following code.`* [...] *`Insert the following code into the stackButton_Click event handler.`* [...] *`In the Code Editor, insert the following code into the StackView class definition`* [...] *`Add a call to the InitializeImages method in the StackView class constructor`*. I'm really stumped. Did you read the tutorial?